# How to generate a map file wth platformio

Tags: platformio

How do I generate a Map file from platformio ?
Framework is mbed for stm32

I've tried passing linker flags in various ways but I get various errors

```
1. build_flags= -Wl, -Map=mapfile.map
2. build_flags= -Wl, Map=mapfile.map
```

For `1.` I get the error message `arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Map=mapfile.map'`

For `2.` I get the linker error message `ld.exe: error: 'Map=mapfile.map' not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax of passing the build flags is not correct. Here is how to do it:

```
build_flags = -Wl,-Map,output.map
```

Reference: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html